# PopulateView function being fired many times before stopping

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm using the following code to fill a list with data from a child within firebase database. The list is filled successfully, but I've got an issue: `FirebaseListAdapter` is being called multiple times before stopping, what does not occur when I use it in other activities.

One weird thing is that when I click a specific `listView` item, data from another item is passed through my openChat intent, what makes wrong data be retrieved to the chat activity I open. It seems that the calling multiple times thing is messing all the data.

Can someone point out what might be wrong with my code and/or what I must do to optimize it?

```js
//database references
chatsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chats").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()); //the children of this are other users IDs
usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");

////////// code for populateView I use within FirebaseListAdapter  ///////////
FirebaseListAdapter<ChatUsers> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatUsers>(getActivity(), ChatUsers.class, R.layout.item_user_listing, chatsRef) {
protected void populateView(View view, ChatUsers chatUsers, int position) {

                TextView nameChatItemList = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameChatItemList);
                id_other_user = getRef(position).getKey();

                usersRef.child(id_other_user).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        //for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                        Toast.makeText(mActivity, dataSnapshot.getValue().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();                    
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

                view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent openChat= new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Chat.class);
                        openChat.putExtra("iduser_chat", id_outro_usuario);
                        openChat.putExtra("name_user_chat", name);
                        startActivity(openChat);
                    }
                });
}

}
```

**EDIT** Changes implemented as suggested by Farmaan

```js
FirebaseListAdapter<ChatUsers> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatUsers>(getActivity(), ChatUsers.class, R.layout.item_user_listing, ChatsRef) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View view, ChatUsers chatUsers, int position) {

                TextView nomeImageChatItemList = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nomeChatItemList);

                String id_other_user = getRef(position).getKey();
                usersRef.child(id_other_user).addListenerForSingleValue(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                                              view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                usersRef.child(id_other_user).addListenerForSingleValue(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();

                                        Intent openChat = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Chat.class);
                                        openChat.putExtra("iduser_chat", id_other_user);
                                        openChat.putExtra("nameuser_chat", name);
                                        startActivity(openChat);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code for FirebaseListAdapter.

Comment: Updated as you suggested, @AlexMamo.

Answer (score 0):

Since `id_other_user` and `name` are the class level field and you are updating it every time you populate the view.So the last view which is populated will decide the user id and the name.That's wrong with your code.

```
chatsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chats").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()); //the children of this are other users IDs
        usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");

        ////////// code for populateView I use within FirebaseListAdapter  ///////////
        protected void populateView (View view, ChatUsuarios chatUsuarios,int position){

            TextView nameChatItemList = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameChatItemList);
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String id_other_user = getRef(position).getKey();

                    usersRef.child(id_other_user).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            //for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                            String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            Intent openChat = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Chat.class);
                            openChat.putExtra("iduser_chat", id_other_user);
                            openChat.putExtra("name_user_chat", name);
                            startActivity(openChat);

                            Toast.makeText(mActivity, dataSnapshot.getValue().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: I need to show the retrieved names on the ListView items so that the current user knows who he's about to talk with when he clicks a specific item. Do I have to call the listener before the onClickListener and, as you suggested, inside the onClickListener as well?

Comment: First of all, make all the variable as local i.e id_other_user and name.Then once you retrieve the key for the user, attach the SingleValueEventListener.Attach the click listener for the view on onDataChange() method.Here you will have access to both the id_other_user and name variable

Comment: I have implemented as you suggested, and it worked for passing the right data to the specific chat window. Thanks for that! But I see the FirebaseListAdapter keeps being called multiple times though there is no change being made to the database from which I'm retrivieving that data. What might be the issue here?

Comment: How do know  FirebaseListAdapter keeps being called multiple times?

Comment: The following toast is called more times than the number of names I have within the chatUsers database: `Toast.makeText(mActivity, dataSnapshot.getValue().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()` . I also implemented a toast in the first line of populateView to show the position it's currently passing through. The result is that it keeps showing alternatively 1, 2, 3,... 1, 2, 3...

Comment: Can you upload the entire list adapter class, so that I can debug that in a better way?

Comment: I'm sorry for the huge delay, Farmaan! I edited my post with what you asked. I hope you can help to understand what's going on. I edited my code using what I've understood from your suggestions.

Comment: Using toasts, I see the FirebaseListAdapter execute something like 50 times before getting into the usersRef listener only 1 time... Weird, isn't it?

Comment: If Toast is fired from the onDataChange method, the intent for Chat Activity should also be fired like 50 times, which is not happening.You are wrong somewhere else

Comment: FirebaseListAdapter is skipping the usersRef listener in every iteration. I tried everything I know to fix this.